# Eclipse RCP 3 - Perspective view is not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm currently working on Eclipse RCP project following [this tutorial](https://o7planning.org/10185/eclipse-rcp-3-tutorial-for-beginners-workbench-application), but somehow my custom perspective is not working, so I cannot add any views into my window.

I constructed extensions like this :
[image]

So desired output should look like this :
[image]

But my application still looks like :
[image]

Perspective id is correctly connected, as instruction said me so.

But my application only shows menu bar, cool bar, and toolbar.

Also in **AppliationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor** class, I defined **preWindowOpen()** function like this :

```
    public void preWindowOpen() {
        IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
        configurer.setInitialSize(new Point(400, 300));
        configurer.setShowCoolBar(true); // default
        configurer.setShowStatusLine(true); // default
        
        // not Working -> Maybe current version of RCP is outdated??
        // Or Because it uses zulu instead of Oracle JavaSE?
        // Show MenuBar
        configurer.setShowMenuBar(true);
        // Show PerspectiveBar
        configurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(true);
        // Show FastViewBars
        configurer.setShowFastViewBars(true);
        // Show ProgressIndicator
        configurer.setShowProgressIndicator(true);
        
        configurer.setTitle("Hello RCP"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
```

but setShowMenuBar, setShowPerspectiveBar, and setShowFastViewBars don't make any difference.

How can I activate perspective so that my view can be shown in my window? Does it have to do with RCP Target settings?

Comment: Have you defined a perspective in the `org.eclipse.ui.perspective` extension point? And set it to be the default perspective? You might also want to look at [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse3RCP/article.html) or even consider doing a more modern Eclipse 4 RCP [see here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html)

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your comment! I defined `org.eclipse.ui.perspective` extension point. I also looked into Vogella tutorial, but `configurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(true);` simply doesn't work. Is there any other way to set my perspective to be the default perspective other than connect my perspective java class to `org.eclipse.ui.perspectives`? And sadly, I should develop my plugins using RCP 3, due to compatibility issue :(

Comment: You set the default perspective in the `WorkbenchAdvisor` by overriding the `getInitialWindowPerspectiveId` method.